# What are the parts of the Spring framework that does work with Appengine

Tags: spring, google-app-engine

Right now, I have been facing so much issue running some parts of the Spring Framework, like I have no problems running my Appengine web app with Spring MVC however have so many issues running Spring Data on top of Appengine.

I wan't to know which part of the framework have been tested to work with Appengine (AE)?

- Does Spring Security work with AE?
- Does Spring Data work with AE?

I'm guessing that there is no planned support for these frameworks at all for AE. However, hopefully I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest looking here:  https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava

Spring Security is listed as SEMI-COMPATIBLE.

Answer (score 0):

As for Spring Security, it works great. You'll just have to enable sessions. And if you want to apply the SPring filter on static files, make sure to exclude them from the static resources in appengine-web.xml.

As for Spring Data, I've never tried it but you might be able to use the JPA and REST sub-projects at least.

Comment: My question was like years old already...Yup I was able to make GAE work with Spring and Spring Security Cheers!